# 2D Convolution Runtime using Python FFTW vs. Numpy FFT

Tags: python, numpy, fftw, pyfftw

I've been playing with Python's FFT functions in order to convolve a 2D kernel across a 2D lattice. Unsatisfied with the performance speed of the Numpy code, I tried implementing PyFFTW3 and was surprised to see an increased runtime. Is there any straightforward way of further optimizing this calculation either via PyFFTW3 or other packages (i.e., Scipy.signal)?

The Numpy vs PyFFTW3 scripts are compared below.

```
import numpy as np
from math import *
import pyfftw

U = 100

### 2D kernel ###
m = np.arange(U)
i = m.reshape(U,1)
j = m.reshape(1,U)

r = np.minimum(i, U-i)**2 + np.minimum(j, U-j)**2
ker = np.exp(-(r)**2)
ker = ker/np.sum(ker)

### 2D lattice ###
lattice = np.random.randint(3, size=(U,U))

def fft_numpy():
    v1 = np.fft.fft2(ker)       
    v2 = np.fft.fft2(lattice)        
    v0 = np.fft.ifft2(v1*v2)      
    dd = np.around(np.abs(v0), decimals=3)  
    return v1, v2, dd

def fft_pyfftw():    
    v1 = pyfftw.interfaces.numpy_fft.fft2(ker)       
    v2 = pyfftw.interfaces.numpy_fft.fft2(lattice)        
    v0 = pyfftw.interfaces.numpy_fft.ifft2(v1*v2)      
    dd = np.around(np.abs(v0), decimals=3)  
    return v1, v2, dd


>> from timeit import timeit
>> timeit(fft_numpy, number=5000)
5.781297922134399
>> timeit(fft_pyfftw, number=5000)
5.930016040802002
```

Comment: I can't replicate your results. How did you get pyfftw (which I assume you mean, and not pyFFTW3)?

Comment: I also can't replicate your results. Using your code, 5000 reps of `fft_numpy()` takes about 8.5 sec on my machine, whereas 5000 reps `fft_pyfftw()` takes about 6.2 sec.

Comment: @Henry Could you not replicate it only in terms of runtime? My laptop is fairly new so that might make a difference? I installed pyfftw from the package website.

Comment: @neither-nor which package website? What operating system are you running? I'd be surprised if the newness is what is making the difference.